# Is there a default arara rule for ConTeXt?

Tags: context, arara

I'm trying to make a simple Hello, World example for ConTeXt.
The file itself works, but I can't manage to instruct `arara` to compile it with `texexec`.

```
% arara: context
\starttext
Hello, World!
\stoptext
```

Neither of the rules `context` or `texexec` exist in the search path,
  but I can't imagine there is *no* rule for ConTeXt.
(The absence of one though will make for a nice `arara`-'Hello World'.)

Comment: AFAIK there is no `context` rule. But it's not too hard to write one... it added one to my personal rules a few weeks ago

Comment: looking in `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules`, it doesn't appear that one exists. If you (or whoever) make(s) it, you should submit a `pull` request to the project on [github](https://github.com/cereda/arara). Constructing a simple rule should be straight forward enough- I would do it, but I don't know any of the options that it would need

Comment: What is the advantage of having an arara rule for context? Unlike LaTeX, `context` is a wrapper around a lua script that runs the context format as many times as need. The `context` script runs bibtex as well. Index sorting, etc are handled natively by the script.

Comment: @Aditya Not too familiar with ConTeXt—definitely didn't know that! I think the proper answer to this question is pretty apparent at this point. Since you have a reason as to why it's unnecessary, would you mind posting this as an answer? :)

Comment: @SeanAllred: Done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LaTeX compiation tools such `arara`, `latexmk`, `rubber`, etc are not needed for ConTeXt.

In LaTeX, the basic commands such as `latex`, `pdflatex`, `luatatex` *just* run the underlying TeX engine with LaTeX format pre-loaded. Features such as bibliography, index, glossary, etc are handled by external tools, and it is the responsibility of the user to run these tools. Furthermore, it is up to the user to run LaTeX appropriate number of times to get the cross-references etc right.

In contrast, in ConTeXt the basic commands `context` and `texexec` are wrappers around scripts written in lua and ruby respectively that take care of everything. Sorting of indexes and glossaries are handled the ConTeXt format, and the wrapper scripts run bibtex if needed and also compile the file as many times as needed.

Coming back to the question at hand, there is no need for a context rule for arara.

Comment: */asking as someone who doesn't know much about ConTeXt/* but `context` *does* have options, doesn't it? or does a user only ever need to run `context myfile` without any other options? if it does take options, then it seems like an `arara` rule may well be appropriate

Comment: You can specify context options in the tex file anyways. I'll update my answer when I am on a computer

Comment: Nine years on, and no answer. I have posted another question about this. I am using Arara with shortcut keys and, rather than having to mouse-click through drop-down menus to get the appropriate compiler for ConTeXt, I'd like to use Arara as the default handler of the compilation steps.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running arara version 5.1.0 or later, you can use arara's integrated `context` rule (see [the CHANGELOG](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/blob/development/CHANGELOG.md#510-2020-04-03) and [the manual](https://islandoftex.gitlab.io/arara/manual/rules/#context)). For most files, it's as easy as putting `% arara: context` at the top of your file.

I also disagree with Aditya's statement

> Coming back to the question at hand, there is no need for a context rule for arara.

because the nice thing about this rule (and why it was added in the first place) is that you can run arara on each and every TeX document you may have, be it LaTeX or ConTeXt, therefore eliminating the need to branch your compilation flow if you have a repository of a mix of LaTeX and ConTeXt documents.

However, the other points are perfectly valid, if you don't need the `arara` indirection for a unified compilation flow, calling the `context` wrapper is the way to go.

Comment: Can I ask for an arara rule for pandoc so that I can run all my tex and markdown files using arara? [Of course, this is a comment made in jest :-) but ... ]